# Any ruby library to inspect what are the arguments that a certain methods take?

Tags: ruby, reflection, rubygems

is there any library that can inspect and display what are the arguments that a method takes?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Is there a way to return a method parameter names in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2452077/#2452322), [Reflection on method parameters in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3456827/#3460072).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any third-party libraries or even RubyGems that can do this reliably. It just isn't possible to do this kind of inspection given the limited reflection facilities Ruby provides.

You will have to make do with what is available in the core library, which is basically [`Method#parameters`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Method%3aparameters):

```
def foo(a, b=nil, *c, d, &e); end
method(:foo).parameters
  # => [[:req, :a], [:opt, :b], [:rest, :c], [:req, :d], [:block, :e]]
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. I'd really like it if Ruby listed the names of the parameters when you have an ArgumentError because you have the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 7):

There's [Method#arity](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Method.html#M001066) that lists how many arguments a method can take.

However, you can't determine what types of objects a method expects. That just isn't in the nature of Ruby.